# Laravel relationships: get the relation of an array of models

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, relationship

I have an array of a specific model, retrieved from the database, let's say:

```
$entries = Entry::with('area')->get();
```

I would like to get **all of those** 'Area' that are related with the entries.

An entry is related to one, and just one, area.

I can loop through the `$entries` array, getting the `Area` for each one of them and storing it in another array, taking care to avoid duplicates (yes, I want a "distinct" of the areas).

Isn't there a better solution? Even taking all areas to process them after (removing duplicates) would be better (I think) than looping through the `$entries` array.

Comment: Do you want distinct area for entries as final result?

Comment: Yes! Because an area can have a lot of entries, so it will appear a lot of times. I just want to know which areas requested entries.

Comment: An area has to be related to some entry?,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use `has` in conjunction with `with`.

```
$entries = Entry::has('area')->with('area')->get();
```

This will return only `Entry`s which have a related `Area`

Your question is a little confusing, it sounds like you want to get `Area`s which have `Entry`s in which case you would start with the `Area` object`.

```
$areas = Area::has('entries')->get();
```

And that would return only the `Area`s which have at least one `Entry`.  It would not also eager load the entries, if you need that data as well, you can chain the `with()` just like in the first example.

Answer (score 1):

An approach could be, get all entries id areas, after get all Areas:

```
$ids =  Entry::all(['area_id'])->toArray();
$areas = Area::whereIn($ids)->distinct()->get();
```